# Add mtime to grep -c output and sort the output by mtime

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, awk, grep

I have a directory full of logs named in the following style:

```
info.log00001
info.log00002
info.log00003
...
info.log09999
info.log
```

#### My current output (using grep -c)

I need to analyze the frequency a particular error that happens occasionally, so go to that directory and use `grep -crw . -e "FooException BarError" | sort -n | less` obtaining something like:

```
./info.log00001: 1
./info.log00002: 0
./info.log00003: 42
...
./info.log09999: 25
./info.log: 0
```

Then, I can `ls -lt` to see their modification date and analyze when the error happened the most.

#### My desired output (with count and date)

Anyway, I'd like find a way to get an output with the count and the date in the same line. That would make my analysis easier. I would like something as:

```
2015-09-31 10:00 ./info.log00001: 1
2015-09-31 10:15 ./info.log00002: 0
2015-09-31 10:30 ./info.log00003: 42
...
2016-04-01 13:20 ./info.log09999: 25
2015-09-31 13:27 ./info.log: 0
```

#### Additional info

Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this with only one command, but first throwing `grep`'s output to a file and then processing that file would make it, too.

Also, I really don't care about the date format or whether the date is at the end or at the beginning of the line. All I want to to is to have the files sorted by date starting with the oldest (which is also the file with the lowest number in its name)

I found a way to accomplish [something similar with `awk`](https://serverfault.com/a/667409), but in my case it would not work, since it parses the filename from `grep`'s output, and in my case, `grep`'s output has more text that just the path to the file.

I'd really appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: Are the date-times inside the logs? Or must you depend on the file's timestamp? If the former, consider installing "histogram", a wrapper around awk. https://github.com/otheus/histogram If the latter, I could extend its functionality.

Comment: Actually, I want to print the timestamp of the last modification of each log. Something similar to what you get when doing `ls -lt`

Comment: The answer you referenced uses awk to invoke the "stat" command. You could do that within histogram because its just a wrapper for awk, but does all the counting for you. Anyway, I think awk is the most useful tool here. A perl oneliner would also work very well. The trick is to use ONLY awk or perl

Comment: I'd wrote one but it's too difficult from my phone'

Comment: @don_crissti that's brilliant. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: |(on laptop now) I actually dont see why chaos's answer wouldn't work for you. His awk divides grep's output into (1) filename as $1 and (2) the whole line. It doesn't matter what output `grep` has. The only reason it wouldn't work is if your filenames have embedded ':' characters.

Comment: I am currently not on my computer, but I do have find. I'll try it later. In the meantime, I suggest you to make that solution an answer. It looks pretty elegant for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `gnu find` - and assuming none of your file names contains newlines - you could use `find`'s [`-printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Print-File-Information.html#Print-File-Information) to output the `mtime` in the desired format + the file name then run `grep` to get the count:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %p: ' -exec grep -cw "whatever" {} \; | sort -k1,1 -k2,2
```

---

Alternatively, with `zsh` you could glob and sort by modification time (via [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) - `.` selects regular files, `Om` sorts in descending order by *mtime*) and then for each file print the `mtime` using the [`stat`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fstat-Module) module, the file name and then, again, get the count via `grep`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
for f in ./**/*(.Om)
do
printf '%s %s\t%s %s: ' $(zstat -F '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M' +mtime -- $f) $f
grep -cw "whatever"  $f
done
```

Comment: These assume you're trying to search through all regular files. Adjust per your needs, e.g. use find with `-type f -name info.log\*` or `zsh` with `for f in ./**/info.log*(.Om)` to match file names as in your example.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Anyway, I'd appreaciate if you'd explain every part of your command so that this can be usefule for future reference for other people. (For instance, why do you need the empty brackets after grep?)

Comment: This is a nice solution. It will call grep for each file individually so that might slow it down

Comment: @Sam - I've added some short explanations and links - it's all in the man pages. As to `{}` : `man find` states: _The string '{}'  is  replaced by the current file name being processed._ @glenn - thanks, yours's nice too.

Answer (score 3):

A bash construct

```
shopt -s globstar
join -o 1.2,0,2.2 -t$'\034' <(stat -c $'%n\034%y' ** | sort) \
                            <(grep -crw "..." | sort | sed -r $'s/:([^:]*)/\034\\1/') \
                             | tr '\034' '\t'
```

There's some funky stuff in there with `\034` -- that's the octal value for the `FS` character. It is *conceivable* that you have existing filenames with that character in the name, you can change that delimiter char if you need to.

The `stat` command spits out the filename and the modified time for each file recursively.

You are familiar with the grep command. I translate the last colon to the FS char.

I have to use bash's ANSI-C quoting syntax for both stat and sed to get the FS char in there.

The `join` command joins the output of stat with that of grep, and outputs "date FS filename FS count"

Then I translate FS to a plain tab.

Comment: Hah! I'm glad you answered this one! I thought about `join`, but as a one liner, it's beyond my ways of thinking. :)

Answer (score 3):

Perl based solution:

```
perl -lne 'if ($.==1) {
 print localtime($t)." $f: $c\n" if defined $t; 
 $c=0; $f=$ARGV; $t=(stat($f))[7];} $c++ if /$expr/o; 
} BEGIN { $expr=shift @ARGV; push @ARGV,"/etc/hosts"; 
' "search-expression" info.log
```

Note: untested.

Some standard perl trickery here. `-n` wraps `while (<>) {` around your code. When `$.` is 1, it's a new file. If we have processed a file, print out the summary information - timestamp, filename, count. Now, for the first line only, get the current filename, the file's mtime timestamp, and reset the counter. For each line, increment the counter if it matches the desired regular expression. End the while loop and start some initiation code, which is executed *before* the previous block. Take the first argument as the regex to match on each line. Now, to the argument list, remove the first argument. Then, *append* a dummy file to the arg list which will trigger the final `print` expression. It's a bit of a harmless hack.